# Cycling through Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have a javascript array, `mediaSizes` as follows: `['xs','md','lg']`.

I'm using a variable `media` to refer to the specific index in the array. So media can either be 0, 1, or 2. So `mediaSizes[media]` should either output `xs`, `md`, or `lg`.

I have up and down arrows for user to cycle through this array. However, when the user clicks the up arrow, and the `media` value is `2`, I want the user to cycle back down to `xs`. Similarly, if the user presses the down arrow on `xs` I want them to cycle through to large.

I have the following `if` `else` statement, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
  var mediaSizes = ['xs','md','lg'];

  var media = 0;

  $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];

  $scope.changeMedia = function(direction) {
    if (media > 2 || media < 0) {
      media = 0;
    } else { 
      if (direction == 'up') {
        media ++;
        $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
      } else {
        media --;
        $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
      }
    }   
  }
```

Right now, I settled for setting the `media` value to 0 for the sake of getting it to work. There has to be an easier way to cycle through 0, 1, 2...

Comment: Should `var mediaDisplay` be `$scope.mediaDisplay` (or just `mediaDisplay`, depending on what `$scope` is?) Otherwise, the value of `mediaDisplay` is scoped to the changeMedia function...

Comment: your `var mediaDisplay` isn't actually changing anything.

Comment: Supposed to be $scope. I was changing it for the sake of simplicity, looks like it did the opposite. See edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick for incrementing a value that you want to wrap around is to use the `%` operator.  For decrementing, you just have to brute force it and check for negative values:

```
 var mediaSizes = ['xs','md','lg'];

  var media = 0;

  $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];

  var changeMedia = function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'up') {
          media = ++media % mediaSizes.length;
      } else {
          if (--media < 0) media += mediaSizes.length;
      }
      $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
  }
```

The `%` operator is handy when incrementing because it will guarentee a value between `0` and `operand - 1`.  So `media % mediaSizes.length` will always be a legal index of the array and it will work for wrapping around as you increment media.

Unfortunately, the `%` operator doesn't do what you want for negative numbers so if we find a negative number, we have to do something different.  In this case, I just chose to add `mediaSizes.length` which will cause `-1` to wrap around to the last index.

FYI, note I'm using `mediaSizes.length` rather than any hard-coded constants so this code would continue to work flawlessly even if you added more mediaSizes to the array.  This is one of the principles of more robust code that automatically handles changes elsewhere.

---

For code cleanliness, this might be a nice place to capture some variables in a closure to keep them out of the global scope:

```
var changeMedia = (function() {
      var mediaSizes = ['xs','md','lg'];
      var media = 0;
      $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];

      return function(direction) {
          if (direction === 'up') {
              media = ++media % mediaSizes.length;
          } else {
              if (--media < 0) media += mediaSizes.length;
          }
          $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
      }
})();
```

Comment: @Himmel - Do you realize that you can upvote all answers that are providing helpful info?  And, I assume you know that if one solves your problem, you can/should select a "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  Further [info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) on upvoting.

Comment: I do know this, thanks. I got pulled away from the computer for a second. But fully intend on learning a few of these helpful lessons in modulo use and `if` `then` ordering when I get a second. I want to wrap my head around your explanation of brute forcing the decrementing, as well as @alexpods explanation of ternery operators.

Comment: is ++media the same as media++?

Comment: @Himmel - One is pre-increment, the other is post-increment.  See [this article](http://jsforallof.us/2014/07/10/pre-increment-vs-post-increment/) for explanation.  Sometimes, there is no difference, but in the cases where I use it, pre-increment and pre-decrement is needed so the rest of the expression is based on the changed value.

Comment: So in the `if` statement... let's say `media` = 0.  `media` evaluates to the remainder of the modulus, or remainder value of "pre-incremental" 0, which is 1

Comment: In this if statement `if (--media < 0) media += mediaSizes.length;`, it decrements media by `1` so if it was `0`, then it is now `-1` and that value is used for the comparison `< 0` which is true, so it adds `3` and you end up at a value of `2` which is the end of the array which is what you want.  If it was `if (media-- < 0) media += mediaSizes.length;`, then the `< 0` comparison would be done on the value before the decrement  which is not what is wanted here.

Comment: In this statement `media = ++media % mediaSizes.length;`, `media` is increased by one and then that newly incremented value is `% mediaSizes.length`.  It's the same as `media = (media + 1) % mediaSizes.length;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70443/discussion-between-himmel-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect in several ways.

1. It does not cycle down
2. You must chance `mediaDisplay` property of scope, not some global `mediaDisplay` object. **UPD**: already fixed
3. Incorrect incrementation and decrementation. For example if current `media` == 2 and user are making `up` direction, then you are incrementing that value (`media`++) and then trying to get `mediaSizes[3]` which does not exist of course.

Use this code instead:

```
var mediaSizes = ['xs','md','lg'];

var media = 0;

$scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];

var changeMedia = function(direction) {
    switch (direction) {
        case 'up':
            media = media === 2 ? 0 : media+1;
            break;
        case 'down':
            media = media === 0 ? 2 : media-1;
            break;
    }
    $scope.mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
};
```

**UPD** 
What about `media = media === 2 ? 0 : media+1` - here we use [ternary opertator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

First check if `media` === 2.

- If `true` - ternary operator return `0` (we must set `media` to zero, as there is no media with index == 3)
- If `false` - ternary operator return `media+1` value.

Almost the same logic for decrementation, but in that case we check on `media` === 0 instead of `media` === 2.

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain the `media = media === 2 ? 0 : media+1` line?

Comment: @Himmel I added small explanation. Hope it will hep you.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
  if (direction == 'up') {
    media ++;
    if(media > 2){
       media = 0;
    }
    var mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
  } else {
    media --;
    if(media < 0){
       media = 2;
    }
    var mediaDisplay = mediaSizes[media];
  }
```